# mySQL Query Count Distinct and Percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble creating a query that will report on training completions by users that are grouped by district within a region.  For one training course the report needs to show for each district

- Number of users assigned course
- Number of users completed course
- Percentage of users completed course

The output report should look like this (without the periods).:

District.........Assigned.......Completed....%

Arkansas..........20..............15...............75%

Illinois...............80..............80...............100%

Iowa.................10...............8.................80%

Michigan..........30..............20................66%

Here's the SQL query I have tried using

```
Select  mytable.district as District,

(Select Count(Distinct mytable.user_id)
     From mytable
     Where mytable.district = District AND
     mytable.training_title = 'My Course') As 'Assigned',

(Select Count(Distinct mytable.user_id) 
     From mytable
     Where mytable.training_status = "Completed" AND
        mytable.district = District AND
        mytable.training_title = 'My Course') as 'Completed',

Concat(Round(100 * (Select Count(Distinct mytable.user_id) 
     From mytable
     Where mytable.training_status = "Completed" AND
     mytable.district = District AND
     mytable.training_title = 'My Course') / (Select Count(Distinct mytable.user_id)
     From mytable
     Where 
        mytable.district = District AND
        mytable.training_title = 'My Course'),0 ),"%") as '%'   

From  mytable  
Where mytable.region = 'Midwest'
Group by District
```

It doesn't work at all like this.  However if I substitute one of the district values (such as Arkansas) in for  'District' in the WHERE clause I can get the correct values for that district.  However i need to find all of the districts for each region and calculate the values for district.  This is only one of the regions I need to create the query for.

Two key issues:

- All of the data exists in one table in my database.  I have consolidated and imported it from another database.
- The data contains duplicates  Therefore I must use Distinct to eliminate the duplicates from the results.

Suggestions?  Thanks in advance for your assistance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you could just sum things up as you want them and `GROUP BY` district. The subquery will take care of the duplicate rows.

```sql
SELECT 
  district,
  COUNT(*) Assigned,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN training_status='Completed' THEN 1 END) Completed,
  CONCAT(COUNT(CASE WHEN training_status='Completed' THEN 1 END) /
  COUNT(*) * 100, '%') `%`
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mytable  
  WHERE mytable.region = 'Midwest'
    AND mytable.training_title = 'My Course') z
GROUP BY district;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/204a2/3).

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  However there are two more complicating issues I need to understand how to overcome.  First, there are duplicates in the data.  How does the query above help me eliminate the duplicates?


Second, in real life I am querying for results for multiple courses and trying to put them into a table from left to right; Course 1 Assigned, Course 1 Completed, Course 1 %, Course 2 Assigned, Course 2 Completed, Course 2 %, etc.  How can I modify the query to support  this requirement?  The courses are known and can be defined in the query.

Comment: @mb87 Removing the duplicates in a sub query now. For #2 I'd need some sample data to test with, and a desired result. Could you add that to the question?

Comment: Joachim.  I have added some data to the SQLfiddle test to represent Course2 and Course3.  Can you go look there and see how this might work?  I REALLY appreciate your help with this!

Comment: @mb87 Can't find a link to your fiddle... could you add that?

Comment: @mb87 Something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/648839/1)? Note that the 3 course types are basically copy & paste of each other which is why the query is so verbose. That also means that there may be ways to simplify the query if there are many columns.

Comment: Thanks Joachim.  My apologies but I'm going to ask one last question.  On your [SQLfiddle]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/648839/1 page you will see that for Course1 (ID 1) and Course2 (ID 2) there are duplicate data.  For the same user, one says Assigned and one say Completed.  Completed supersedes Assigned.  In the results table the correct completion % should be 50% (1 of 2 completed) instead of 1 of 3.  The assigned count should be 2 as well.  Any idea how to overcome this duplication?   It is real in my data.  Thanks again!

Comment: @mb87 Simplest to solve that is to use a `GROUP BY` to drop the lower (in alphabetical order since it's a string) value in the subquery to remove the duplicates. Something like [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a4a69/1).